# Is the limit definition of the derivative symmetric?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I want to show that $f'(x+h)=f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. When I consider the secant line formed by the two points in the limit, I see no reason to dismiss the idea that the slope of the secant line also approaches the slope of the tangent line at $(x,f(x+h))$ as well. If we let $c=x+h$, substituting into the conventional definition gives $f'(x)=\lim_{c\rightarrow x}\frac{f(c)-f(x)}{c-x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(c)=f'(x+h)$. My question may boil down to whether the input to the limit is reversible (is ${c\rightarrow x}$ equivalent to ${x\rightarrow c}?)$. The idea that one point is stationary and the other one is "moving" seems like an unnecessary construct. What really matters is that the distance between the points approaches zero, right?

Comment: The left-most part of $f'(x+h)=f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: You claim these points are infinitely close to each other yet I do not see an appropriate limit. It is entirely true (for a function $f$ with continuous derivative) that $\lim_{h\to 0}f'(x+h) = f'(x)$ but this is not significant. "What really matters is that the distance between the points approaches zero, right?" - You have to choose a single point to evaluate the derivative at, this is the 'stationary' point.

Comment: Professor Vector, do you mean that f′(x+h)=f′(x) doesn't make sense because the slopes at these points are not necessarily equal? I would agree in general for two points that lie on a function that is not linear, but in the limit doesn't local linearity allow for the equality?

Comment: RyanK, so my notation is incorrect? If I edit my original equation as $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}f'(x+h)=f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ then it is correct?

Comment: might want to use different letters for each $h$ since they do not represent the same thing. As long as the derivative is continuous, this statement is correct (but again, different $h$'s on the left and right). @BobTivnan

Comment: It matters that the specific point under consideration is stationary and other is moving. Just the distance between them tending to zero won't suffice alone.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. When you write down the following formula $$f'(x)=\lim_{c \to x}\frac{f(c)-f(x)}{c-x},$$
$x$ is always a fixed number, and $c$ is a variable. Hence you can't obatain $$\lim_{c \to x}\frac{f(c)-f(x)}{c-x}=\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}.$$

Comment: I suspect that I am wrong, but you're explanation is not convincing me. What I am really asking is,  if the points are infinitesimally close to each other why does one point get a preference over the other in the limit? Isn't the slope of the secant line approaching the slope of the tangent for both points?

Comment: @BobTivnan: the idea of infinitesimally close is something which belongs to non-standard analysis. Typical calculus textbooks don't use this approach. If you are interested in this approach please see Keisler's book on infinitesimal calculus. In the common approach two points are either same or different and not infinitesimally close.

Comment: @BobTivnan: and thus the slope of secant tends to the slope of tangent at the specified point $x$. It has no relation to what happens at $x+h$.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question. However, I feel you've misled yourself by using $h$ in the point and the limit. Indeed, replacing one with $k$, we see: $$f'(x+k)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+k+h)-f(x+k)}{h}$$ from which we observe $$\lim_{k\to 0}\bigg[\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+k+h)-f(x+k)}{h}\bigg]=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$$

In other words, $$\lim_{k\to 0} f'(x+k)=f'(x)$$

Using $h$ twice for two different ideas is what caused the inaccurate statement $f'(x+h)=f(x)$.

Comment: I see. My reply to Ryan K's comment above seems to fix the problem if I replace h with k on the left side of the equation. Thanks!